# jquery regex replace word space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, space

I'm wondering if anyone could help me.
I need to replace a string with another string in HTML code.
Let's say there is a headline

### I am foo with x-foo bar.

.
The word "foo" should be replaced, if it has any char right before itself other than space. So the first " foo" should not be replaced but the second "-foo" should be replaced.
Also it should replace foo and Foo.

My code would be something like this:

```
$("h2").html( $("h2").html().replace(/Foo|foo/g, "<span class='replacedFoo'>F</span>oo") );
```

This code replaces all foo's and Foo's. But also " foo". Can anyone help?

- replace "somethingFoo"
- don't replace " Foo"

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Use a non-space representation token [**`(?:^|\S)[Ff]oo`**](https://www.regex101.com/r/cbobOA/1)

Comment: O M G ! That's it. Thank you sooo much! You saved my day. :)

Comment: Note that matching the non-whitespace character preceding `[Ff]oo` will take it out of the resulting string (since it's included in what you're replacing).

Comment: I just realized that! So the result is not "-<span>F</span>oo" but "<span>F</span>oo".
That's not what I want. :D
Any other idea how to change the regex?

Comment: To make it more complicated:
What we have:

    <h2>This is Something-Foo and Dr. Foo</h2>

What we want:

    <h2>This is <strong>Something-</strong><span class="replacedFoo">F</span>oo and Dr. Foo</h2>

- Replace the whole word right before "Foo" with strong-tag.
- Replace the F of "Foo" if there is no space but any other character right before "Foo" - match "foo" and "Foo".
- Do not replace " Foo".

Any more regex-masters? :)

Answer (score 0):

change all foo & Foo with a space before it or at the beginning of a line with Bar

$("h2").html( $("h2").html().replace(/\Sfoo/gi,"Bar") )

\S matches all non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h2").html( $("h2").html().replace(/(^|\S)([Ff])oo/g, "$1<span class='replacedFoo'>$2</span>oo") );
```

`(\S)` - match any non-whitespace character and capture it so we can put it back after replacing.

`([Ff])` - match both cases of 'F' and capture so we can replace with the same case.

`"$1<span...` - insert the non-whitespace character we found at the beginning of the match.

`...replacedFoo'>$2</span>...` - insert the same case of 'F' we found in the match.

```js
function replaceFoo(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\S)([Ff])oo/g, "$1<span class='replacedFoo'>$2</span>oo");
}

console.log(replaceFoo('I am fooFoo'));
console.log(replaceFoo('Foo foo foo foofoo'));
```

Comment: @MrLumbergh I've edited my answer with a runnable snippet to demonstrate that the regex works. The problem must be elsewhere; perhaps you mean to user `$('h2').text()` instead of `.html()`?

Answer (score 0):

To make it more complicated:
What we have:

```
<h2>This is Something-Foo and Dr. Foo</h2>
```

What we want:

```
<h2>This is <strong>Something-</strong><span class="replacedFoo">F</span>oo and Dr. Foo</h2>
```

- Replace the whole word right before "Foo" with strong-tag.
- Replace the F of "Foo" if there is no space but any other character right before "Foo" - match "foo" and "Foo".
- Do not replace " Foo".

Any more regex-masters? :)

Comment: This is adding to your initial question. You should edit your question and include this, or ask a new question for this specific problem.